# Ansible: Trying to make remote computer check out from SVN

Tags: svn, ansible

I'm trying to get Ansible to check out my repo from SVN.  I've managed to connect to the remote machine via ssh, by installing sshpass, and including --ask-pass.

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
```

My tasks/main.yml file contains:

```
---
- name: Checkout from SVN
  subversion: repo=svn+http://svnSite-url/repos/PROG dest=/opt/export export=True username=svnuser password=svnpass
```

Now, I've tested that URL with that username and password, and it logs in.

But with ansible, it dies in the GATHERING FACTS phase, and I get a big bunch of goop about muxservers and then an error message:

```
debug2: process_mux_new_session: channel 1: request tty 1, X 0, agent 0, subsys 0, term "xterm", cmd "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1408977295.75-11416778392185 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1408977295.75-11416778392185 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1408977295.75-11416778392185'", env 0
debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
mm_receive_fd: no message header
process_mux_new_session: failed to receive fd 0 from slave
```

Some more goop and a final error message:

```
mux_client_request_session: read from master failed: Connection reset by peer
Failed to connect to new control master
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Note that if I put --username and --password, it gets past the GATHERING FACTS stage, and into the SVN Checkout stage, does a good effort at connecting, and then I get:

```
failed: [svnSite-url] => {"failed": true}
msg: unsupported parameter for module: --password

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/myadminusername/site.retry

svnSite-url              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Manager keys from SVN

```
- apt: name=subversion state=present
- subversion: 
     repo={{ repo }}
     username={{ username }}
     password={{ password }}
     dest={{ SVN_dst }} 
- assemble: 
     src={{ SVN_dst }}{{ item.name  }}/ dest={{ item.path }}
  with_items:
    - { name: 'root', path: '/root/.ssh/authorized_keys' }
    - { name: 'ubuntu', path: '/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys' }
```

in VARS
repo: http://svn.example/svn/sshkeys/servers/example/{{ ansible_nodename }}/

IHMO the problem is in line:

subversion: repo=**svn+http**://